# Is there a way to add a type assertion / annotation to a template input variable?

Tags: angular, angular6

## Background

I have a template that looks like this (I'm using some component that uses this as the basis for a repeated item, it's the `<p-pickList>`, but the question is not specific about that component, just as an example)

For background, let's say I have a type `Foo` and my component has a `foos: Foo[]`, I'm feeding it to the `<p-pickList>` component under the `[source]` attribute and its doing the internal `*ngFor` for it, all I have to do is provide a template

```html
 <ng-template let-foo pTemplate="item">
   ...
   {{ foo.anythingGoesHereWithNoWarningAndNoAutocomplete }}
```

However, the type information on `foo` seems to be lost.

I'm a big fan of type safety and I like that Intellij (or any other editor) can show me a warning if inside the template I do something like specifying an invalid attribute of `foo`

If I had a regular `*ngFor`, it would infer the type of `foo`

```html
<div *ngFor="let foo of foos">
  {{ foo.autoCompleteWorksInMostIDEsAsWellAsWarningIfInvalidProp }}
```

## Questions:

1. Is there any syntax that will allow me to hint the type of `let-foo`? (and hopefully most IDE's will recognize).
2. If I don't want to rely on IDE's, is there a way to have the ng compiler type check `foo` (declared by let-foo)?

tl;dr is there a syntax that let me type annotate the template input variable?
e.g. something like this made up syntax?

`let-foo="$implicit as Foo"` or `let-foo-type="Foo"`?

## Workaround

One silly idea is to have an identity function in my component, e.g.

```js
identity(foo: Foo): Foo {
  return foo;
}
```

But doing

```html
{{ identity(foo).fooProp }}
```

Is not a big improvement over

```html
{{ (foo as Foo).fooProp }}`
```

Comment: Not sure if `fulltemplatetypecheck` option would work? https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#fulltemplatetypecheck

Comment: maybe a pipe that receive the type parameter? something like {{ youwhareverData | typeChecker:FooClass }}

Comment: I think your prod build will fail if that variable doesn't exist. 
To have intellisense, I  think you need an extension for your editor.

Comment: This is more like a feature request that you need to submit to Angular team

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ng-template - typed variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55458421/ng-template-typed-variable)

Comment: Prod build will not recognise if an argument doesn't exists even with fullTemplateTypeCheck and strictTemplates

Comment: Shouldn't this be addressed in one of upcoming Angular releases?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

VSCode should have that feature out of the box, just tested in stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-type-assertion?file=src/app/app.component.html

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it isn't using an extension? My VS Code on Windows 10 does not have this. I know that this extension can do HTML intellisense: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template

Comment: Hey Boland! I this example I used the VSCode online by stackblitz, I couldn't find any documentation about any plugin they use in VSCode

Comment: Stackblitz uses [Angular Language Service](https://angular.io/guide/language-service)

Comment: @hamilton.lima this question is about type assertion / annotation to a template input variable. Reference to object type in template input variable gets lost even on Stackblitz.

Comment: @abdulrafay as you can see from the screenshot stackblitz was able to validate if the attribute name was valid for that object, so the information about type is not lost

Comment: you are not checking template input variable in your code. Updated your Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-type-assertion-wndgva?file=src/app/app.component.html 

check that type info is being lost in `ng-template` `let-foo`

Comment: Good point! I rewrote your block changing to *ngFor and that keeps the type, take a look https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-type-assertion?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: You are showing what he already told us in question: *If I had a regular *ngFor, it would infer the type of foo*. Your code block is still not using [template input variables][1]. Question clearly asks for this: *Is there any syntax that will allow me to hint the type of let-foo?* 
 [1]: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-input-variable

Comment: How come this is accepted answer....

Answer (score 4):

Let's see what angular has similar to that and how it work!

```html
<p *ngFor="let number of [{v: 101},{v: 102}, {v: 103}]">{{number.v}}</p>
```

We can rewrite it without `*` magic

```html
<ng-template ngFor let-number [ngForOf]="[{v: 101},{v: 102}, {v: 103}]">
  <p>{{number.v}}</p>
</ng-template>
```

Without watchers (`ngDoCheck`) it can be the same as (but `ngTemplateOutlet` [have no typecheck](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6.1.7/packages/common/src/directives/ng_template_outlet.ts#L43)):

```html
<ng-template let-number #templateRef>
  <p>{{number.v}}</p>
</ng-template>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="templateRef; context: {$implicit: {v: 101}}"></ng-container>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="templateRef; context: {$implicit: {v: 102}}"></ng-container>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="templateRef; context: {$implicit: {v: 103}}"></ng-container>
```

Or we can create it by ourselves

```html
// template
<button (click)=create(templateRef)>create</button>
```

```js
// TS
constructor(private _viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { ... }

create(templateRef: TemplateRef<{$implicit: {v: number;}}>) {
    this._viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(templateRef, {$implicit: {v: 101}});
    this._viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(templateRef, {$implicit: {v: 102}});
    this._viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(templateRef, {$implicit: {v: 103}});
}
```

**TL;DR**

Template typecheck magic happens inside `viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView`. (for example [`ngFor`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6.1.7/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts#L165));
But it assume what templateRef accepts.

Angular can compile in `AOT`:

```html
<p *ngFor="let num of [{v:1}, {v:2}]">
  {{num.does.not.exist.completly}}
</p>
```

So as i understood we should assume what types templates have but do check when template is instantiated (by `createEmbeddedView`);

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there is no any type information. `<ng-template let-foo pTemplate="item">` - is just template declaration, it is not yet bound to any type/context, just some dynamic type that has or may have `anythingGoesHereWithNoWarningAndNoAutocomplete` field. Without proper generics support it is not possible to have this kind of typesafety.

Answer (score 2):

Found this issue and proposed solution to allow template input variables to publish type information so that IDEs can provide better completion on github [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12398). This feature is currently under development and hopefully it'll be out in the future release of Angular. You should use [Angular Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) extension in VS Code or Sublime Text for now. You can rest assured about the extension's support because it's being worked on by the Angular team. For more info, checkout this [readme](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2150b45954cd2776c0adc52951c7b450a2eb66b8/aio/content/guide/language-service.md) and [docs](https://angular.io/guide/language-service).

As you mentioned it can be achieved by using identity function but it will cause heavy performance issue and it'll be a mess maintaining this functionality for different types.

Answer (score 2):

**This can be solved by wrapping your variable inside another `ng-template`**

This is somehow another workaround, but I liked a lot more than the other solutions here because it just adds 2 more lines of code in the HTML, of course if you're using your variable only 1 or 2 times [this other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55458722/1657465) is better. My answer:

Instead of this:

```html
<p *ngTemplateOutlet="foo; context: {$implicit: {fooProp: 'Hello!'}}"></p>
<ng-template #foo let-args>
    This is untyped: {{ args.fooProp }}<br>
</ng-template>
```

Do this:

```html
<p *ngTemplateOutlet="foo; context: {$implicit: {fooProp: 'Hello!'}}"></p>
<ng-template #foo let-untypedArgs>
    <ng-template [ngIf]="identity(untypedArgs)" let-args="ngIf">
        This is typed: {{ args.fooProp }}<br>
    </ng-template>
</ng-template>
```

```js
identity(foo: Foo): Foo {
    return foo;
}
```

As stated already by everyone, the type assertion is noticed by the IDE when `*ngFor` is in use. It also works when using `*ngIf`. Of course there's a downside with this solution as the inner `<ng-template>` is rendered later because of the `[ngIf]`.

With this, now if you add an invalid property to your context, you'll get the following compilation error which is great, [here's a stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-template-typed?file=src/app/app.component.ts):

> Property 'newFooProp' does not exist on type 'Foo'.

I came up with this solution by just reading the [documentation here](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#shorthand-examples):

[image]

I tested this solution and works on Angular 11 using vscode with `angularCompilerOptions` properties `enableIvy` and `fullTemplateTypeCheck` setted on `true`.

Also, [Angular Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) should be installed, this solution is needed even with [ALS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) installed because the template can be called from anywhere, and so, [ALS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) doesn't have a way to know the context params being passed. This can be easily tested in the [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-template-typed?file=src/app/app.component.ts) I've added, just rename `fooProp` to `fooProp1`, you'll see that the untyped example shows an empty value, and the typed one throws an error.

Comment: I believe you meant `<ng-template [ngIf]="identity(untypedArgs)" let-args="ngIf">`, but even having the right `angularCompilerOptions` the variable is still considered as `any` in my tests.

Comment: This solution is not hack, It's just taking advantage of the expected behaviour of `[ngIf]`, So please let us know if you found the reason of why it doesn't work in your tests!

Comment: @Mart, I've fixed the code to `identity(untypedArgs)`, thank you. Also, i've added a reference to Angular Language Service, do you have that plugin installed?

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template

Comment: Yes, I have the Angular Language Service plugin and this trick worked on a new simple project. I have to figure out why my large project doesn't behave the same way.