# how to make angular kendo-grid typesafe

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, ng-template, typesafe

Variable `dataItem` has type `any`, I guess the type can't be inferred from the `[kendoGridBinding]` which binds to `Array<T>`? Do I need to use a type guard or type assertion on each column?

```html
<kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="processTable()">
    <kendo-grid-column 
       field="qty"  <-- not type safe
       title="Qty Required"> 
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column title="Processed">
      <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
        {{ dataItem.events.length }}  <--- not type safe
      </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
   ...
```

I have a growing number of tables and refactoring the code e.g. renaming variables could in this situation cause errors undetected by the compiler.

Comment: I think there is nothing you can do. In theory in future they aim to provide all TS/JS capabilities in the templates including typecasts. This would help. But for now it seems rather impossible under the circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your issue can be solved by wrapping the `let-dataItem`:**

Instead of this:

```html
<kendo-grid-column title="Processed">
  <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
    {{ dataItem.events.length }}  <--- not type safe
  </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Do this:

```html
<kendo-grid-column title="Processed">
  <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-untypedDataItem>
    <ng-container *ngIf="identity(untypedDataItem) as dataItem">
        {{ dataItem.events.length }}  <--- Now is type safe
    </ng-container>
  </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

```js
// typescript
identity(foo: any): MyType {
    return foo;
}
```

This is more or less the same answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67198974/1657465), you can check other people approaches there.

---

The type assertion is noticed by the IDE when `*ngFor` or `*ngIf` is in use. The downside with this solution is that the inner  is rendered "later" because of the `*ngIf`. And also, `ngZone` is called at every lifecycle which might result in a little performance drawback.

Comment: thanks, was thinking might have to do something like this, but good to know the caveats you gave regarding performance etc. Let's see if this changes in v17 with the new syntax